# How can I call a api paralleled at the same time with postman? How could I do it?

Tags: api, post, postman, restful-url, postman-pre-request-script

I am using postman and want to test a restful api with calling it at the same time, which same time api trigger at the same time. So i can check what happen if the same records posted in a db.
Could anyone help ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: what do you mean by calling it twice? Is there any single api method you want to call two times? or all the apis needs to call twice?

Comment: oh sorry for my poor English. it should be that I want to call a api parallel at the same time.

Comment: Open two windows and hit the same request from both

Comment: cannot to make it at the same time....

Comment: As per my knowledge, there is no direct way